# Agrupar un Json por el id

Tags: javascript, angular5

Hola tengo el siguiente `JSON`:

```
{
"estado":"NY",
"ciudad":"brooklyn",
"poblacion": "5millones",
"area": "750000km"
},
{
"estado":"NY",
"ciudad":"bufalo",
"poblacion: "3millones",
"area": "70000km"
},
{
"estado":"CA",
"ciudad":"LosAngeles",
"poblacion": "2millones",
"area": "40000km"
}
```

Deseo mostrar un arreglo de esta manera, tomando solo el valor(agrupandolo por ciudad aun asi esta se repita) estado y ciudad, obviando los demás.

```
{
  {estado: "NY" , ciudades: ["bufalo", "brooklyn"]}
},
{
  {estado: "CA", ciudades: ["los Angeles"]}
}
```

Estoy utilizando el `lodash` de `js _.groupBy` pero no me ejecuta el resultado que deseo.

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es un array de arrays, cada array con un único elemento? Parece raro

Comment: @PabloLozano si, agrupar por estado y que cada estado tenga sus ciudades, poniendolo de una manera mas sencilla

Comment: ¿No sería más cómodo algo como `[{estado: "NY" , ciudades: ["bufalo", "brooklyn"]},
{estado: "CA", ciudades: ["los Angeles"]}]`?

Comment: En cualquier caso, podrías usar un Map como acumulador en un `reduce`, obteniendo luego los valores del mismo. No necesitas ninguna librería y es sencillo. Y deberías añadir el código de lo que has intentado hacer

Comment: @PabloLozano si eso es lo que busco..

Answer (score 0):

emplee el siguiente código que dio resultado a mi incognita..

```
    let result = array.reduce((prev, current, index, arr) => {
    let exists = prev.find(x => x.estado === current.estado);
    if (!exists) {
    exists = {estado: current.estado, ciudades: []};
    prev.push(exists);
    }
    if (current.ciudad!= null){
    exists.ciudades.push(current.ciudad);
    }
    return prev;
    }, []);
    console.log(result);
```